# Objective C : Custom class in identity inspector creates a new object of that class?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, model-view-controller, controller, uistoryboard

In a storyboard when I add a new view (for example a `TableView`) I can select a class in the "Custom class" field in the identity inspector.

If I understand the rule of this class, I expect this class "answer" to messages sent to my tableview (i.e. this class is my table viewcontroller) and when I run my project it seems to do what I want.

My question is: To do this, I expected my Xcode automatically instantiates an object of my controller class and "link" this object to my GUI in storyboard.

However, I expected that if I override the init method of my controller class with

```
-(id) init
{
  self=[super init];
  NSLog(@"object controller created automatically");
  return self;
}
```

I have the string in output when is created my controller object.
Instead, I have no output.
Why is this happenig and what is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you question you want a message to be **printed** whenever your `viewController` is initialised.

**Why** dont you write the code in the `viewDidLoad`?

Like:

In your `YourControllerClass.m`

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];

NSLog(@"Controller created");

}
```

Now set the class of the controller in the storyboard to `YourControllerClass`and the message should be printed whenever your controller is created.

Cheers

P.s.: If you still need help or got a question, please write a comment.

Answer (score 2):

UIView set up by storyboard never called init.
Instead, you should use `- (void)awakeFromNib` in which your outlet has been ready to use.

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    NSLog(@"object controller created automatically");
}
```

From `awakeFromNib` documentation:

> Objects that conform to the `NSCoding` protocol (including all subclasses of `UIView` and `UIViewController`) are initialized using their `initWithCoder:` method. All objects that do not conform to the `NSCoding` protocol are initialized using their `init` method.

Comment: So, it create a controller object using another method? It does something like `[[mycontrollerclass alloc] awakeFromNib]` ? :)

Comment: @volperossa  Thought you were talking about view, sorry about that! Since you want to do some init work for UIViewController,  viewDidLoad is your choice as MasterRazer said.  BTW, if you want that for UIView which created from a Nib, then awakeFromNib is a good place to go

Comment: @volperossa If it would be a UIView you can also use if(uiview) -> print! (in the viewDidLoad or any other method you prefer) ;)